# Insert SAS table values into Oracle table

Tags: oracle, sas

I have created a SAS table like

```
Create table DX.SAS_Table as 
select * from connection to oracle
(
  select * from my table
)
```

Now I want to insert count of SAS_Table into another Oracle table, so I did this

```
Proc sql;
connect to oracle (connection..!)
execute(
    INSERT INTO TEST_SAS_INSERT
    select count(*) from SAS_Table
) by oracle;
```

quit;
It throwing me the error **ERROR: ORACLE execute error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**, I tried this Select count(*) from Dual its working but not from SAS_Table I understood this throw error Oracle considering SAS_table as oracle table, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in the EXECUTE is done exclusively in the Oracle session.  The Oracle session can not reach across the network and read your SAS tables.

You can create a library reference to Oracle and insert into the Oracle table from SAS.

```
libname MYORA ....;
proc sql;
  insert into MYORA.TEST_SAS_INSERT (my_count_column_name)
  select count(*) from DX.SAS_Table;
```

You could also perform the count and store the result in a macro variable and use that in an insert statement with a values clause

```
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into :MY_COUNT from DX.SAS_table;
  connect ...
  execute (
    insert into MYORA.TEST_SAS_INSERT (my_count_column_name)
    values (&MY_COUNT);
  ) by Oracle
```

Comment: I think you missed the  "&" sign when referencing the macro: values(&MY_COUNT)

Answer (score 2):

connect statement does everything in oracle and will not anything about SAS tables. This can be solved in two ways. By using explicit sql-pass through or implicit pass through

first method Either move SAS table to Oracle and then do an insert like
/* creating oracle table */

```
  proc sql;
  create table oratable.tablename as
  select *
  from SAS_Table;
  quit;
```

then doing insert in connect statement(explicit pass through method)

```
 proc sql;
 connect to oracle (user=&myid orapw=&mypwd path="&mydb");
  execute ( INSERT INTO schema.finaloratable
         select count(*) from schema.tablename) by oracle; 
  disconnect from oracle;
  quit;
```

or use libname method without connect statement (implicit pass through method)

libname oratable oracle user=user password=password path=path;

```
proc sql;
Insert into oratable.tablename as
select count(*)
from 
on SAS_Table
quit;
```